# Failed to launch instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, icehouse

/etc/nova/nova-scheduler.log

```
2015-06-09 16:33:21.478 22017 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'9d4d80a0-ba41-4a31-a272-a6a49f3dcabe']
2015-06-09 16:33:21.487 22017 WARNING nova.scheduler.filters.compute_filter [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] (compute2, compute2) ram:3257 disk:87040 io_ops:0 instances:1 has not been heard from in a while
2015-06-09 16:33:21.487 22017 WARNING nova.scheduler.filters.compute_filter [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] (network, network) ram:3257 disk:59392 io_ops:0 instances:0 has not been heard from in a while
2015-06-09 16:33:21.488 22017 WARNING nova.scheduler.filters.compute_filter [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] (compute2-ThinkCentre-M62z, compute2-ThinkCentre-M62z) ram:3257 disk:87040 io_ops:0 instances:0 has not been heard from in a while
2015-06-09 16:33:21.582 22017 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] Choosing host WeighedHost [host: compute1, weight: 1.0] for instance 9d4d80a0-ba41-4a31-a272-a6a49f3dcabe
2015-06-09 16:33:21.676 22017 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.18.190:5672
2015-06-09 16:33:23.558 22017 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'9d4d80a0-ba41-4a31-a272-a6a49f3dcabe']
2015-06-09 16:33:23.559 22017 ERROR nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] [instance: 9d4d80a0-ba41-4a31-a272-a6a49f3dcabe] Error from last host: compute1 (node compute1): [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1379, in _build_instance\n    set_access_ip=set_access_ip)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 410, in decorated_function\n    return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1797, in _spawn\n    LOG.exception(_(\'Instance failed to spawn\'), instance=instance)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 68, in __exit__\n    six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1794, in _spawn\n    block_device_info)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 2292, in spawn\n    write_to_disk=True)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3486, in to_xml\n    disk_info, rescue, block_device_info)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3300, in get_guest_config\n    flavor)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/vif.py", line 384, in get_config\n    _("Unexpected vif_type=%s") % vif_type)\n', u'NovaException: Unexpected vif_type=binding_failed\n']
2015-06-09 16:33:23.565 22017 WARNING nova.scheduler.filters.compute_filter [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] (compute2, compute2) ram:3257 disk:87040 io_ops:0 instances:1 has not been heard from in a while
2015-06-09 16:33:23.566 22017 WARNING nova.scheduler.filters.compute_filter [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] (network, network) ram:3257 disk:59392 io_ops:0 instances:0 has not been heard from in a while
2015-06-09 16:33:23.567 22017 WARNING nova.scheduler.filters.compute_filter [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] (compute2-ThinkCentre-M62z, compute2-ThinkCentre-M62z) ram:3257 disk:87040 io_ops:0 instances:0 has not been heard from in a while
2015-06-09 16:33:23.574 22017 INFO nova.filters [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] Filter ComputeFilter returned 0 hosts
2015-06-09 16:33:23.575 22017 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-0a1934f9-2983-4d96-8410-f2a8747963da c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620] [instance: 9d4d80a0-ba41-4a31-a272-a6a49f3dcabe] Setting instance to ERROR state.
```

ovs-vsctl show

```
   Bridge "br-eth2"
        Port "eth2-br-ex"
            Interface "eth2-br-ex"
        Port "phy-br-eth2"
            Interface "phy-br-eth2"
        Port "br-eth2"
            Interface "br-eth2"
                type: internal
    Bridge br-int
        fail_mode: secure
        Port "tapb49c4a78-43"
            tag: 4095
            Interface "tapb49c4a78-43"
                type: internal
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port patch-tun
            Interface patch-tun
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-int}
        Port "int-br-eth2"
            Interface "int-br-eth2"
        Port "int-br-eth1"
            Interface "int-br-eth1"
    Bridge br-tun
        Port "gre-c0a8125b"
            Interface "gre-c0a8125b"
                type: gre
                options: {in_key=flow, local_ip="192.168.18.190", out_key=flow, remote_ip="192.168.18.91"}
        Port patch-int
            Interface patch-int
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-tun}
        Port br-tun
            Interface br-tun
                type: internal
        Port "gre-c0a812d1"
            Interface "gre-c0a812d1"
                type: gre
                options: {in_key=flow, local_ip="192.168.18.190", out_key=flow, remote_ip="192.168.18.209"}
    Bridge "br-eth1"
        Port "eth1-br-ex"
            Interface "eth1-br-ex"
        Port "phy-br-eth1"
            Interface "phy-br-eth1"
        Port "br-eth1"
            Interface "br-eth1"
                type: internal
    Bridge br-ex
        Port "ex-br-eth1"
            Interface "ex-br-eth1"
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
        Port "ex-br-eth2"
            Interface "ex-br-eth2"
    ovs_version: "2.0.2"
```

When i try to launch an instance,I get the following:

```
    DEBUG (session:195) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://controller:35357/v2.0 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient"
    INFO (connectionpool:203) Starting new HTTP connection (1): controller
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 614
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] content-length: 614 vary: X-Auth-Token connection: keep-alive date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:10 GMT content-type: application/json x-distribution: Ubuntu
    RESP BODY: {"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2014-04-17T00:00:00Z", "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v2.0+json"}, {"base": "application/xml", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v2.0+xml"}], "id": "v2.0", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:35357/v2.0/", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-identity-service/2.0/content/", "type": "text/html", "rel": "describedby"}, {"href": "http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-identity-service/2.0/identity-dev-guide-2.0.pdf", "type": "application/pdf", "rel": "describedby"}]}}

    DEBUG (v2:76) Making authentication request to http://controller:35357/v2.0/tokens
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "POST /v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1" 200 1657
    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}6881a35ec4df7e87de1fa3152ae912a8795a5738"
    INFO (connectionpool:203) Starting new HTTP connection (1): controller
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba HTTP/1.1" 200 728
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:11 GMT connection: keep-alive content-type: application/json content-length: 728 x-compute-request-id: req-e083f293-96a1-4772-ade6-3733be2cbd30
    RESP BODY: {"image": {"status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2015-05-25T16:03:33Z", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "rel": "bookmark"}, {"href": "http://controller:9292/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image", "rel": "alternate"}], "id": "326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 66294, "name": "cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-disk.img", "created": "2015-05-25T16:03:33Z", "minDisk": 0, "progress": 100, "minRam": 0, "metadata": {}}}

    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors?is_public=None -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}6881a35ec4df7e87de1fa3152ae912a8795a5738"
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors?is_public=None HTTP/1.1" 200 1209
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:11 GMT connection: keep-alive content-type: application/json content-length: 1209 x-compute-request-id: req-fa0ccd53-ee36-4a63-a864-e4e129ecae70
    RESP BODY: {"flavors": [{"id": "1", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.tiny"}, {"id": "2", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/2", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/2", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.small"}, {"id": "3", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/3", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/3", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.medium"}, {"id": "4", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/4", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/4", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.large"}, {"id": "5", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/5", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/5", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.xlarge"}]}
     DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'2015' for 'year' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'06' for 'monthdash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 6 for 'month' with default 6
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'09' for 'daydash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 9 for 'day' with default 9
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'12' for 'hour' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'27' for 'minute' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'10' for 'second' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None,     'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1 -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}6881a35ec4df7e87de1fa3152ae912a8795a5738"
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 418
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:11 GMT connection: keep-alive content-type: application/json content-length: 418 x-compute-request-id: req-5565dd95-bd88-4b4a-9b1b-467dfefe7953
    RESP BODY: {"flavor": {"name": "m1.tiny", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}], "ram": 512, "OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled": false, "vcpus": 1, "swap": "", "os-flavor-access:is_public": true, "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 0, "disk": 1, "id": "1"}}

    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
   'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'2015' for 'year' with default None
   http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}6881a35ec4df7e87de1fa3152ae912a8795a5738" -d '{"server": {"name": "test_vm_name", "imageRef": "326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "flavorRef": "1", "max_count": 1, "min_count": 1, "networks": [{"uuid": "7129c8fe-eeca-4c5a-8ee2-893366fd7df6"}]}}'
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "POST /v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers HTTP/1.1" 202 436
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [202] content-length: 436 x-compute-request-id: req-1ecaefaa-f292-4bdf-9e9b-991d626d6b54 connection: keep-alive location: http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers/b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:12 GMT content-type: application/json
    RESP BODY: {"server": {"security_groups": [{"name": "default"}], "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", "id": "b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers/b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers/b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d", "rel": "bookmark"}], "adminPass": "tgFtEWfXr6TR"}}

    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
   http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers/b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}6881a35ec4df7e87de1fa3152ae912a8795a5738"
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers/b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d HTTP/1.1" 200 1423
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:12 GMT connection: keep-alive content-type: application/json content-length: 1423 x-compute-request-id: req-b31a9c47-4e45-4831-9f97-b792c71a31ff
    RESP BODY: {"server": {"status": "BUILD", "updated": "2015-06-09T11:27:12Z", "hostId": "", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": null, "addresses": {}, "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers/b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/servers/b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d", "rel": "bookmark"}], "key_name": null, "image": {"id": "326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "OS-EXT-STS:task_state": "scheduling", "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "building", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-0000004a", "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": null, "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": null, "flavor": {"id": "1", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d", "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null, "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "nova", "user_id": "c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b", "name": "test_vm_name", "created": "2015-06-09T11:27:12Z", "tenant_id": "6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [], "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 0, "config_drive": "", "metadata": {}}}

    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'2015' for 'year' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'06' for 'monthdash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 6 for 'month' with default 6
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'09' for 'daydash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 9 for 'day' with default 9
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'12' for 'hour' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'27' for 'minute' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'10' for 'second' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'2015' for 'year' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'06' for 'monthdash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 6 for 'month' with default 6
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'09' for 'daydash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 9 for 'day' with default 9
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'12' for 'hour' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'27' for 'minute' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'10' for 'second' with default None
    DEBUG (session:195) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1 -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}6881a35ec4df7e87de1fa3152ae912a8795a5738"
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 418
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:12 GMT connection: keep-alive content-type: application/json content-length: 418 x-compute-request-id: req-4b45e8d2-2c55-4d0e-8ecd-a2cee734a429
    RESP BODY: {"flavor": {"name": "m1.tiny", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}], "ram": 512, "OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled": false, "vcpus": 1, "swap": "", "os-flavor-access:is_public": true, "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 0, "disk": 1, "id": "1"}}

    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'2015' for 'year' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'06' for 'monthdash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 6 for 'month' with default 6
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'09' for 'daydash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 9 for 'day' with default 9
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'12' for 'hour' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'27' for 'minute' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'10' for 'second' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:184) Parsed 2015-06-09T12:27:10Z into {'tz_sign': None, 'second_fraction': None, 'hour': u'12', 'daydash': u'09', 'tz_hour': None, 'month': None, 'timezone': u'Z', 'second': u'10', 'tz_minute': None, 'year': u'2015', 'separator': u'T', 'monthdash': u'06', 'day': None, 'minute': u'27'} with default timezone 
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'2015' for 'year' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'06' for 'monthdash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 6 for 'month' with default 6
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'09' for 'daydash' with default 1
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got 9 for 'day' with default 9
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'12' for 'hour' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'27' for 'minute' with default None
    DEBUG (iso8601:140) Got u'10' for 'second' with default None
    DEBUG (session:195) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}6881a35ec4df7e87de1fa3152ae912a8795a5738"
    DEBUG (connectionpool:383) "GET /v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba HTTP/1.1" 200 728
    DEBUG (session:224) RESP: [200] date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 11:27:12 GMT connection: keep-alive content-type: application/json content-length: 728 x-compute-request-id: req-45b27af5-07b8-4309-bd48-0b62dfc0770d
    RESP BODY: {"image": {"status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2015-05-25T16:03:33Z", "links": [{"href": "http://controller:8774/v2/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://controller:8774/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "rel": "bookmark"}, {"href": "http://controller:9292/6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620/images/326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image", "rel": "alternate"}], "id": "326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba", "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 66294, "name": "cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-disk.img", "created": "2015-05-25T16:03:33Z", "minDisk": 0, "progress": 100, "minRam": 0, "metadata": {}}}

    +--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Property                             | Value                                                               |
    +--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | OS-DCF:diskConfig                    | MANUAL                                                              |
    | OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone          | nova                                                                |
    | OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                 | -                                                                   |
    | OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname  | -                                                                   |
    | OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name        | instance-0000004a                                                   |
    | OS-EXT-STS:power_state               | 0                                                                   |
    | OS-EXT-STS:task_state                | scheduling                                                          |
    | OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                  | building                                                            |
    | OS-SRV-USG:launched_at               | -                                                                   |
    | OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at             | -                                                                   |
    | accessIPv4                           |                                                                     |
    | accessIPv6                           |                                                                     |
    | adminPass                            | tgFtEWfXr6TR                                                        |
    | config_drive                         |                                                                     |
    | created                              | 2015-06-09T11:27:12Z                                                |
    | flavor                               | m1.tiny (1)                                                         |
    | hostId                               |                                                                     |
    | id                                   | b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d                                |
    | image                                | cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-disk.img (326ad902-f5a6-4ccc-84e5-0651248efdba) |
    | key_name                             | -                                                                   |
    | metadata                             | {}                                                                  |
    | name                                 | test_vm_name                                                        |
    | os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached | []                                                                  |
    | progress                             | 0                                                                   |
    | security_groups                      | default                                                             |
    | status                               | BUILD                                                               |
    | tenant_id                            | 6c4ce8dfeeef4788a86d520020a50620                                    |
    | updated                              | 2015-06-09T11:27:12Z                                                |
    | user_id                              | c8f956dbaa734f18836628172552645b                                    |
    +--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
    +--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------+
    | ID                                   | Name         | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks               |
    +--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------+
    | b37a7c95-d3cf-4309-9125-57bc8297bf8d | test_vm_name | BUILD  | spawning   | NOSTATE     | demo-net=192.168.18.10 |
    +--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------+
```

After nova list, NETWORKS becomes blank and state becomes ERROR
I HAVE APPLIED MANY OF THE MEASURES SUGGESTED PREVIOUSLY BUT NONE ARE WORKING

Comment: sorry part is somewhat out of correct format.Due to space limit i tried to delete unrelevant part which messed up the things a bit.

Comment: Just posting plain logs foes not give us any salvageable information. Please state your problem at the begging, the things you have tried and then 'present' the error logs.

Comment: i have given schedular logs

Comment: i dont have any error in api logs

Comment: Throw out the client debug logs because these are almost completely useless, and your broken formatting makes the entire question hard to read.  Also, please clearly state your problem at the beginning if your question.  Consider hard-wrapping the log extracts so that we can read them without side scrolling.